# Is it possible to apply computation to RSUs in simulation tools such as Omnet and Veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am researching omnet and veins for a project and i am wondering if computation can be applied to nodes such as RSUs? Can they be configured to aggregate data from multiple vehicles for example? If not, is there any advice on how i could achieve this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

OMNeT++ is written in C++, so you can perform any computation you can think of. As long as you are able to write the algorithm as a C++ program, it will work in your simulation.